# docker commands related problem

Tags: container

I tried:
`:~$docker -d`

```
[/var/lib/docker|99d07396] +job initapi()
[/var/lib/docker|99d07396.initapi()] Creating server
mkdir /var/lib/docker/containers: permission denied[/var/lib/docker|99d07396] -job initapi() = ERR (1)
2014/02/01 20:38:13 initapi: mkdir /var/lib/docker/containers: permission denied
```

tail -f /var/log/kern.log:

```
Feb 2 21:44:18 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6211.765815] cfg80211: (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 2 21:44:18 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6211.765818] cfg80211: (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 2 21:44:18 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6211.765822] cfg80211: (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
Feb 2 21:44:18 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6211.765826] cfg80211: (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm) Feb 2 21:44:19 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6212.855662] wlan0: authenticate with 00:1e:a6:1c:4b:a0
Feb 2 21:44:19 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6212.863401] wlan0: send auth to 00:1e:a6:1c:4b:a0 (try 1/3)
Feb 2 21:44:19 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6212.865598] wlan0: authenticated
Feb 2 21:44:19 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6212.866094] wlan0: associate with 00:1e:a6:1c:4b:a0 (try 1/3)
Feb 2 21:44:19 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6212.869620] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 00:1e:a6:1c:4b:a0 (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=2)
Feb 2 21:44:19 neethu-pc kernel: [ 6212.869702] wlan0: associated
```

sudo docker -d:

```
[/var/lib/docker|99d07396] +job initapi()
[/var/lib/docker|99d07396.initapi()] Creating server    
mkdir /var/lib/docker/containers: permission denied[/var/lib/docker|99d07396] -job initapi() = ERR (1) 2014/02/01 20:38:13 initapi: mkdir /var/lib/docker/containers: permission denied
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Open two terminals, in one run `tail -f /var/log/kern.log` and the other try `docker -d`. Is there any output from the tail command? Please *edit* it into your question.

Comment: i run the command mentioned above,and i got like this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks suspiciously similar to the AppArmor bug they had recently:

https://github.com/dotcloud/docker/issues/5082

Perhaps check /var/log/messages for any apparmor messages e.g.

`cat /var/log/messages | grep -i apparmor | tail`

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Although it may prove to be helpful, your post is not an answer but rather a suggestion or comment. The place for such content is as a comment on the question. Please take a few moments to review the [help center](http://askubuntu.com/help) for tips on when to post comments and when to post something as an answer.

Comment: I wish I could but: "You must have 50 reputation to comment"

Comment: Well, it's not that difficult to gain reputation. Just invest some time sticking around and there will be chances to give answer worth voting.